# How to mix CSS absolute positioning?

Tags: css, user-interface

I need somehow to combine absolute `position` so that `margin-top` will be counting from the second line of the text. For now `margin-top` doesn't work for me.

If I use `relative` position the button goes to the bottom of the page but I need it to stay at the old place but with proper `margin`. How can I achieve this?

```css
#ok_btn {
 width: 120px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-right: 22px;
 margin-top: 22px;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div id="userPopup"
  title="Warning">
  <spring:theme code="text.popup.warning.company_user" />
  <p />
  <button class="tiny button" id="ok_btn"
    onclick="closeDialogUser();">
    <spring:theme code="text.ok" />
  </button>
</div>
```

*The image shows how it is placed now*

[image]

*Should be something like this:*

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you want... is the image the correct result, or the wrong one? Explain better how you want it to work

Comment: Plus, seems like the snipped doesn't work.

Comment: I just need that margin-top work for my button

Comment: Do you mean you want a 22px margin below the "Thank you." text?

Comment: below "and account for your". i.e below the second line of text

Comment: ok, I see... the problem is how will the button know where "account for your" is positioned? For example, if you shrink the size of the container the text lines will change and posibly even overlap the button. I suggest you either put it below all the text, or you absolute position it using bottom/right instead of with margin.